# Best practice to develop offline web app in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, offlineapps

We might need to develop an offline first application based on React.
From the research we did so far, we think there is two important enabling technology for this:

- Offline Application Caching APIs
- Service workers.

However, what confused is that MDN pages of above items list following things.

About application caching:

> Using the application caching feature described here is at this point
>   **highly discouraged**; it’s in the process of being removed from the Web
>   platform. Use Service Workers instead. In fact as of Firefox 44, when
>   AppCache is used to provide offline support for a page a warning
>   message is now displayed in the console advising developers to use
>   Service workers instead (bug 1204581).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Using_the_application_cache

About service workers:

> This is an **experimental** technology Check the Browser compatibility
>   table carefully before using this in production.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers

---

We are interested which approach is currently the most recommended one to write offline first web apps in general?

Comment: You should use Service Workers.

Comment: @SLaks what about it being experimental? so we should check browser compatibility etc.?

Comment: It depends on your target audience and how forward thinking you are. Service workers along with the local cache and indexdb are great, but don't work in all legacy browsers. If you built the website correctly, it will work offline for those it with support for the features, and will work properly online for the rest.  See https://caniuse.com/#search=service%20workers for browser compatibility

Comment: @user3257598 sounds like you may need to develop with service workers with a fallback to application caching so that you can cover all bases.

Comment: @user3257598: OK, so do that.

Comment: @SLaks is there any difference (in terms of available technology) if we want to use this offline web app on the mobile too? (e.g. maybe browser on android doesn't support indexedb etc.)